# How can I update a Stage-based HUD from another Stage's Actor in libGDX?

Tags: libgdx, scene2d

I feel like this is a simple problem, but I'm having issues finding the correct search terms.

I have a `Screen` that includes two `Stage`s.

1. The first, `stage`, contains a number of objects deriving from `Actor` and added via the standard `stage.addActor(Actor)`. This is for the actual game objects.
2. The second, `hudStage`, consists of a single `Table` actor. This table includes a button as well as two `Label`s. This is for the static user interface/HUD.

I'm handling touch events on my custom actors in the game stage like the following:

```
public class GameObject extends Actor {
    private final static String TAG = GameObject.class.getName();
    // ...

    public GameObject() {
        // ...

        addListener(new InputListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                Gdx.app.log(TAG, "touchDown on GameObject actor: <" + x + "," + y + ">");
                return super.touchDown(event, x, y, pointer, button);
            }
        });
    }
```

This works perfectly and logs what I need. However, I would now like to update the HUD with information about the object the user touched.

My screen has defined the `Label` I want to update (added via `hudStage`), but I'm not sure how to go from an actor in `stage` to the screen, or to the `hudStage` label.

```
public class GameScreen implements Screen {
    Stage stage;
    Stage hudStage;
    // This is the label I want to update.
    Label infoLabel;
    // ...
}
```

I know I can call `setText(String)` on the label, but I'm not sure the best way to bubble the click up. Plenty of examples have simplified versions where objects are defined in the main class (in my case, `GameScreen`) and are able to refer to them that way, but I've already broken these apart.

I started to look at creating a custom event that my actor could trigger, and that the stage would handle, but documentation is sparse and I'm not sure this is required.

I've also thought about scrapping the idea of having a label in the `hudStage` and instead having my actor draw text where the HUD would have. However, from what I continue to see, I think Scene2D is the right direction to go for the UI.

Thanks!

EDIT: What I'm looking for:

1. An actor in `GameScreen.stage` is target of a `touchDown` event.
2. Logic in actor fires and updates object.
3. touchDown event in actor finishes by updating `infoLabel` in `GameScreen.hudStage` **or** updates String value in `GameScreen` (if easier, I'll go this route).

Comment: Do the Stage's not have access to each other? And if they don't, why not?

Comment: Good question. I think the answer is no, at least unless you go through `GameScreen`. It looks like the only window I have open is [this answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22375990/11912) about multiple stages. Note that my cameras are different, which made me think two sibling stages would be required.

Comment: But you're already using 2 stages (one for hud and one for the game), how is that any different from the answer you linked?

Comment: It's not different, it's actually why I went with two stages ... Sorry, that was an attempt to answer your question "[I]f they don't, why not?" / why I coded this as I did. I assumed that they would have access to each other if one was the child of another.

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem with your current implementation? What do you by you wanting the click event to bubble up? What is supposed to happen?

Comment: Added an EDIT at the bottom of the answer to hopefully clarify "I would now like to update the HUD with information about the object the user touched. My screen has defined the Label I want to update (added via hudStage), but I'm not sure how to go from an actor in stage to the screen, or to the hudStage label." Thanks!

Comment: I'm running into the exact same problem with the exact same setup, one game stage for the `GameObject`s and an abstract game coordinate system, and a separate stage for the UI using screen coordinates. Initially I was under the impression that Scene2D's event system accounted for passing messages between stages, but it doesn't; as the OP pointed out already, events are only propagated within a single stage. So game events such as "player died" will never reach the UI, but have to be passed on manually. This undermines the whole idea of decoupling objects/layers using message passing.

Comment: I should add, I fixed the problem by using an event broker: the broker holds a reference to the UI stage and is registered as an ordinary game event listener on the game stage. When it receives an event it forwards it to the UI. That way you have a single integration point which isn't too bad.

Answer (score 1):

To make this work you need the two stages to communicate. There are two ways you could have the result you desire.

1. Have each actor you create (that is touchable) contain a reference to the HUD stage. Then when the actor is touched, simply update the HUD by calling a method with the actor as a parameter (`hudStage.update(thisActor)`).
2. Do not assign listeners to your actors. Instead assign a listener to your HUD stage (not the table within it) that listens for clicks on the entire screen. When a click is registered, call `hit(x, y, true)` and see which actor is hit. Call that actor's update method (or whatever it is you want to do when an actor is touched) and update the HUD's info with that actor.

I think these would be the easiest ways to accomplish what you want, but of course, you can make variations on these two ideas as you need.